# Truth table of the conditional

Tags: logic

I am currently studying the conditional. I found myself a bit puzzled with its truth table until I cooked up a few examples in my head. I am not sure if my thinking is concrete, so I post my thinking here to invite corrections.

Let $\mathrm{P: x}$ is a triangle; $\mathrm{Q: x}$ has at least one pair of sides that are mutually perpendicular.

The conditional $\mathrm{P} \rightarrow \mathrm{Q} $ is true when $\mathrm{Q} $ follows from $\mathrm{P} $ or when $\mathrm{P} $ leads us to $\mathrm{Q} $(am I right?).

Let me take a few cases into consideration:

When $\mathrm{x}$ is a right-angled triangle, both $\mathrm{P}$ and $\mathrm{Q} $ are true and it is evident that $\mathrm{Q} $ follows from $\mathrm{P} $. We have, $\mathrm{T} \rightarrow \mathrm{T} $ is $\mathrm{T} $.

When $\mathrm{x}$ is an equilateral triangle, $\mathrm{P} $ is true but $\mathrm{Q} $ is false. The conditional here is false, for an equilateral triangle can never lead us to conclude that one of its angles is a right angle. We have, $\mathrm{T} \rightarrow \mathrm{F} $ is $\mathrm{F} $.

When $\mathrm{x} $ is a square, $\mathrm{P} $ is false but $\mathrm{Q} $ is true. The conditional is true, for a square always leads us to conclude that there is at least one right angle in it. We have, $\mathrm{F} \rightarrow \mathrm{T} $ is $\mathrm{T} $.

When $\mathrm{x} $ is a circle, both $\mathrm{P} $ and $\mathrm{Q} $ are false. A circle leads us to conclude that there is not a single right angle in it. Here, $\mathrm{P} $ leads us to $\mathrm{Q} $. We have, $\mathrm{F} \rightarrow \mathrm{F} $ is $\mathrm{T} $.

I hope that someone spots an error in my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

> The conditional $\mathrm{P} \rightarrow \mathrm{Q} $ is true when $\mathrm{Q} $ follows from $\mathrm{P} $ or when $\mathrm{P} $ leads us to $\mathrm{Q} $ (am I right?).

No: the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication) is True when either the *consequent* $\mathrm{Q}$ is True or the *antecedent* $\mathrm{P}$ is False.

Regarding your example :

> Let $\mathrm{P: x}$ is a triangle; $\mathrm{Q: x}$ has at least one pair of sides that are mutually perpendicular,

maybe we want to find the truth value of the corresponding universally quantified formula :

> $\forall x \ (Px \to Qx)$.

If so, your reasoning is correct : if $x$ is a right-angled triangle, both antecedent and consequent are True, while if $x$ is an equilateral triangle, the antecedent id True and the consequent is False.

Thus, the formula $(Px \to Qx)$ is not always True, i.e. $\forall x \ (Px \to Qx)$ is False.

---

> why the truth table of the conditional is the way it is.

The [propositional connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) are a very simple mathematical model of natural language, suited for modelling Mathematical arguments.

Their definition is through [truth-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Binary_operations) that are "proxy" for the corresponding natural language mechanisms.

Someone works better (negation and conjunction), someone with some arbitrariness (disjunction, inclusive : *vel* instead of *aut*); someone with a big approximation : "if..., then...".

The mathematical model of "if $A$ then $B$" represented by truth-tables does not require any sort of "link" between the two statements : *antecedent* and *consequent*.

What may help (IMO) is the interaction between the truth-functional conditional and the inference rule of [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) that allows us to infer from the *premises* $A$ and $A \rightarrow B$, the *conclusion* $B$.

We must read it as [Gottlob Frege](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) did in his [*Begriffsschrift* (1879)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift) :

> assuming as *true* both the premises, the assumption that $A \rightarrow B$ is *true*, rule-out the row $T-F$ in the truth-table for *implies*, while the assumption that also $A$ is *true* rule out two other rows ($F-F$ and $F-T$, respectively). Then, the conclusion that $B$ is *true* is licensed.

Comment: > No: the conditional is True when either the consequent  is True or the antecedent  is False.

This statement raises a question. Is it just a statement to be followed without questioning or is there a reason behind making such a statement?

Comment: @R004 - in classical logic the *conditional* connective is defined by the truth table and it is said "truth functional", meaning that the truth value of the compund statement depends **only** on the truth value of the composing statements. No "link" (causal7inferential) is needed to assess the resulting truth value : "if Napoleon was a female, then the Moon in made of green cheese" is True.

Comment: Hahaha! Thank you for that! I do know that the conditional is devoid of causality. But what I'm trying to understand is why the truth table of the conditional is the way it is.

Comment: Can I say that an "implication" is true when Q follows from P or when P leads us to Q? If yes, then a true implication would lead us to a true conditional. In the above examples, I have tried to show the truth or falsity of an implication. In doing so, I have shown the truth or falsity of the conditional. Isn't this another way of arriving at the conditional's truth table?